# TypeError: undefined is not a function in bootstrap-file-upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I have a HTML/javascript problem getting the bootstrap-files-upload plugin in grails (vers 2.3.3) to work.

This problem results in a web development tool error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

In the file: **jquery.fileupload-ui.js**

pointing to the line:

```
this._super();
```

Looking at past posts I believe that I am having a problem initializing this correctly from the bootstrap-file-upload plugin. I have tried running document.ready/ window.upload to ensure that the web page is ready prior to running the plugin code but without success.

I'm using an up-to-date version of Chrome as my browser.

Can anyone suggest a resolution?

-mike

Comment: This plugin http://grails.org/plugin/bootstrap-file-upload has not been updated since a year or so. I think you are better off using the core JS and code from here: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @lalit AgarWal - I uploaded the most up-to-date version v 9.8.0 instead of v 9.5.7. Still getting the exact same problem - convinced more than ever that it's an initialization problem.